# Зачем нужен API Key

Tags: php, javascript, алгоритм, api

Те сервисы, у которых есть открытое `API`, обязывают регистрироваться, чтобы получить специальный ключ... то есть `API Key`.. и этот ключ нужно передавать при каждом запросе: `site.ru/{api_key}/{method}/...`

Не понятно, почему они так делают, **если я могу, к примеру, взять у кого-нибудь этот ключ, не регистрируясь...**

так для чего того нужен этот `API Key`? в чем смысл?

Comment: Если кто то используя api-key напишет вирус или другое вредоносное приложение, то ключ заблокируют и приложение работать не будет. так что если кто то дает свои ключи - он это делает на свой страх и риск

Comment: Адекватный народ просто не даст вам свой ключ :)

Comment: Это же про клиентские ключи api?  Типа яндекс метрики,  facebook,  или гугл аналитики?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`API Key` используется как [`CSRF Token`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0) - дабы посылать далеко сразу и без разговоров тех, у кого его нет. Если получил и творишь фигню - можно было бы отозвать. Т. е. средство быстрой модерации.
Так же ключи могут выполнять функции [`Access Token`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0) - таким образом, кто-то (сервис, пользователь) может предоставить доступ до тех ресурсов, к которым доступ запрещён (личные сообщения, приватная информация и т. д.), не делая последние публичными.

---

Брать ключ у кого-то, конечно, можно, вот только ответственность за действия будет нести именно владелец ключа (в некоторых сервисах подобное прямо оговаривают).
Если действия **не** владельца ключа будут деструктивными, администрация удалит владельца (а так же, возможно, отзовёт какие-то оплаченные платные услуги, собранная аудитория под старым ключём). Скомпрометированный ключ иногда дают пересоздать (`SE API`), иногда - только с помощью тех. поддержки.

Answer (score 4):

Обычно API key используется для идентификации сервисом клиента. И по этому ключу сервис определяет какие данные можно отдавать определенному клиенту. 
Обычно еще используется авторизация и выдается токен, который нужно передоверять при каждом запросе к серверу после авторизации.

Владельцы сервиса наверняка не предполагают что вам кто то будет давать свой api_key)