# Rest api + Android клиент: Как отдавать данные только моим приложениям

Tags: java, android, c#, api, аутентификация

Есть rest api сервис без аутентификации пользователей. Сейчас им могут пользоваться все кто угодно. Как реализовать проверку только моих программ-клиентов, чтобы только они могли обмениваться данными.

Comment: Никак? Кто помешает "левым" клиентам представляться как ваши?

Comment: может внедрить в api-сервис api-ключи и их проверку при запросе?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523911/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-api-key
при каждом запросе нужно передавать в параметре api-ключ, он будет только у вас, вы сможете использовать его в своих клиентах, остальные не будут его знать и не смогут сделать запрос

Comment: Но помните что API Key можно "выдрать" из приложения и дальше также пользоваться api. ИМХО, лучше использовать авторизацию на ресурсе, логин/пароль, oauth например.

Comment: api ключ без проблем можно выдрать из пакета и подставить в любое другое приложение. Аутентификация с помощью логин/пароль не подходит

Comment: Тогда вам к сожалению ничего не поможет. Все что работает на стороне по умолчанию считается скомпрометированным.

Answer (score 1):

Используй AccessKey, так к примеру использует Google Rest. Он не работает, если в параметре не указать AccessKey. Пример гугла:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{0}%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key={Твой кей}
```

Comment: Как будет генерироваться AccessKey? или он будет статический и вшит в пакет? но тогда его вытащат

Comment: @sanya920 Как генерировать, чтобы затруднить его компрометацию - это другой, очень обширный, вопрос. Лучше задать его отдельно.

Comment: @eugeneek а по-моему именно в этом и состоит вся суть первоначального вопроса ТС. И без объяснения как генерить, ответ просто не является ответом. (Хотя, тут как ни генери, покуда это будет происходить на клиенте, оно не будет обеспечивать надёжной защиты)

Comment: @playerone "Как отдавать данные только моим приложениям" и "Как спрятать строку в apk" - согласитесь, есть разница. Как первый, так и второй вопрос имеют много решений, разной степени надёжности и могут быть не связаны друг с другом. Поэтому я и предложил задать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @eugeneek разница, конечно, есть. Однако полноценный ответ на первый вопрос, подразумевает так же и ответ на второй (хотя бы поверхностный). Без него, он не только бесполезен для вопрошающего, но и просто не может быть оценен с точки зрения практичности/применимости. Вашу точку зрения я услышал. Не вижу смысла дальше дискутировать, т.к. мы с вами не модераторы всё равно.